# Why does my selection sort fail when I hardcode a non-zero minimum value?

Tags: c, loops, sorting, for-loop, selection-sort

My code isn't performing a selection sort successfully when I specify `min = arr[0]` before entering the loop to process the array, it fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[11] = {7, 12, 4, 28, 3, 15, 7, 3, 89, 1, 12};
    int x, i, next_index;

    /* Select first element (i = 0) first for loop and compare it with all  
       elements of array till the end of array second for loop (so next   
       iteration, when i = 1 the first element will be the smallest one */

    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {   
        // min = arr[0]; /* <-- WHEN I UNCOMMENT THIS THE CODE FAILS. WHY? */

        /* Select min element */
        for (next_index = i + 1; next_index <= 10; next_index++)
        {     
            if (arr[next_index] < arr[i])
            {   
                 /* Swap arr[i] with min value */
                 x = arr[i];
                 arr[i] = arr[next_index];
                 arr[next_index] = x;
            }
        }
     }
     printf("Sorted array: \n");

     for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        printf(" %d \n", arr[i]); 

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What is the purpose of `min` in each iteration of the loop? Can it serve this purpose if you assign it with value of `arr[min]` in any iteration except the first one?

Comment: This is a classic case where your problem should become obvous if you run the program in a debugger and step through your loop while `i>0`

Comment: neither of them are [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

Comment: Please tidy up your code and indent it properly before posting. First time it's ok, but your code has been tidied up by others for several of your questions now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the both approaches are inefficient because there are redundant swaps of elements of the array.

In the second program instead of using in the body of the outer loop the statement

```
min=arr[i];
```

you are using

```
min=arr[0];
```

In this loop

```
printf("sorting array is : \n");
       for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
           {
    printf(" %d \n",min); // as i put value of min in i
           }
```

you are always outputting the last value of the variable `min` outside the loops that sort the array.
.
Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like `10`.

And you should declare variables in the smallest scope where they are used.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int arr[] = { 7, 12, 4, 28, 3, 15, 7, 3, 89, 1, 12 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );    

    printf( "Unsorted array: " );
    for ( size_t  i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf(" %2d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {   
        size_t min_i = i; 

        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++ )
        {     
            if ( arr[j] < arr[min_i] ) min_i = j;
        }

        if ( min_i != i )
        {
            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min_i];
            arr[min_i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    printf( "sorted array:   " );
    for ( size_t  i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf(" %2d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Unsorted array:   7  12   4  28   3  15   7   3  89   1  12 
sorted array:     1   3   3   4   7   7  12  12  15  28  89
```

Answer (score 1):

Second code is not working correctly because you are not swapping values correctly. Secondly the logic of assigning min = arr[0] will mot work, it’s logically wrong. You may need to do like min = arr[i] and swapping the values correctly.